# How to prepare Hop Tea?

Tags: hops

How does one make a "Hop Tea" for taste testing?

I am trying to get a better understanding of different hop flavor profiles. I have heard of making hop teas to do taste tests but I wonder if it's easy as it sounds (hot water+ hops-steep). Has anyone done this, and if there is more than one variety what can be done in between each variety to cleanse the palate?

Comment: See [this question](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/how-can-i-learn-the-distinctive-taste-of-various-hops/3523#3523) on this forum regarding how to learn the character of various hops. The idea of hop teas is discussed in the answers (not in a very positive light): [Link](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/how-can-i-learn-the-distinctive-taste-of-various-hops/3523#3523).

Comment: Remember that a little goes a long way! I just read about someone who added hops to their beef stew hoping it would impart some flavor but it came out awful. They said they were tasting bitterness for hours.

Answer (score 3):

[This blog entry](http://www.bertusbrewery.com/2013/03/dry-hopped-bud-light.html) suggests dry-hopping light beer like Bud Light as an easy way to compare hop flavor profiles. It'd probably taste better than a hop tea, and you can even mix different bottles to see how hops work together!

Comment: Have you or anyone else here, tried this? How long did you leave the hops in for?  Trying to learn my ingredients, I was thinking of the hop tea method but could see the advantages of a Bud Light method (oh the shame of being seen buying Bud Light lol!)

Answer (score 2):

Hop teas are a terrible way to get an idea of a hop's flavor.  They are harsh, astringent and vegetal.  The only usefulness I find at all is in comparing one hop to another.  You won't get a true test of the hops, but you can find out how they're different.  The best way to do it is to adjust the water pH to around 5.5, but the tea will still be disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

My version of a hop tea is exactly that. I make my hop tea by boiling 1 Cup water in pot and take it off the boil and let the hops(roughly 25gm for a 22L batch) sit for 10 minutes in the water.

If I like the flavor then I add that to the brew.

This may not be the correct way but it is how I do it and I have got great results.